# In a domain model who is responsbile to call data mapper?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm learning "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture". I'm confused about data mapper pattern. As far as I know domain model itself should not be aware of existence of different data mappers. Then who is responsible to call data mappers to load or save a domain model objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data mapper is used at the framework level to convert in-memory object representation of data to relational representation in database and vice-a-versa. 
By framework level I mean the ORM provider such as Hibernate, Ibatis etc will use data-mapper layer to create the in-memory domain object after reading the relational database. Similarly, data mapper will convert in-memory domain objects to relational database representation.

As a result, the in-memory domain object itself is decoupled from the complexities of the underlying relational database. The reason domain object is unaware of data mapper is that the framework takes care of executing the data mapper when data is read from database and provides this data as in-memory objects to the code requesting it. Similarly, the code makes the database call on the abstracted out Hibernate\JPA libraries while internally framework uses the data mapper layer to convert the data in this call to appropriate format which the database needs.